# How to do packaging of ADT (Android Development Tools) for PPA?

Tags: package-management, android, ppa, eclipse, packaging

From last few days i am trying to learn packaging in Ubuntu. I successfully created Binary deb of Scilab 5.4.1 & ADT but i don't have any webspace or server to host repository for these packages. So i tried to upload the source files of these packages to launchpad. But for some reason the binary which were compiled by launchpad doesn't contain package files.  Can somebody help me with the procedure to create packages for ppa with binary files in it? I will be very grateful.

I'm placing 'usr/adt/eclipse' & 'usr/adt/sdk' folders in the same directory(adt-22.2.1~ppa1) with debian directory.And using postinst & postrm files to control installation.

thanks !

Regards
Navdeep Singh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks anyway !!! I used brackets ppa & downloaded source for reference , used it as an example to improve my packaging. Thanks to webupd8 for wonderful packaging !!!!

Please help me to test my builds on my ppa ppa:linuxgndu/gajj-sci.

Still i can use some feedbacks & suggestions.